# Prove that $a^n-b^n\not\mid a^n+b^n $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Show that for $a,b,n>1$, $$a^n-b^n\not\mid a^n+b^n $$

By the way of contradiction, Assume $a^n-b^n\mid a^n+b^n $, Hence $$(a^n-b^n, a^n+b^n)= a^n-b^n \\ =(2a^n, a^n+b^n)=(2b^n, a^n+b^n)$$
Well, what’s next?

Comment: Check if $a-b$ divides $a^n+b^n$ as it divides $a^n-b^n$. Is it over the integers?

Comment: Yes $a,b,n\in\mathbb Z$ @Wuestenfux

Comment: $a-b\mid a^n+b^n$ regardless of wether $a^n-b^n\mid a^n+b^n$ or not, just set $a=b+1$ @Wuestenfux